# Swift: How to set inner class array properties into UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, swift, oop

I would like to set the inner class `array` objects to the `UITableViewCell`.
This is my class:

```
import Foundation
class AvailableCoursesInitialResponseModel: BaseObject {
    var availableCourses : [CoursesModel]!
}

class CoursesModel: BaseObject{
    var categoryName : String!
    var categoryData : [categoryDataModel]!
}

class categoryDataModel: BaseObject{
    var classInfo : classInfromationModel!
    var classList : [classListDetailModel]!
}

class classInfromationModel: BaseObject{
    var displayText : Bool!
    var updatedBy : Int!
    var endDate : String!
    var groups : String!
}

class classListDetailModel : BaseObject{
    var courseFee: String!
    var fromTime : NSDate!
    var courseDate : NSDate!
    var location : String!
    var className : String!
    var registration : String!
    var courseCalendarId : Int!
    var toTime : NSDate! 
}
```

I have made a custom `UITableViewCell` as:

```
import UIKit

class AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    var model : classListDetailModel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblDecription: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lblClassName: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

This is the view controller containing `UITableView`:

```
import UIKit 
class AvailableCoursesSecondViewController:   
        UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate{
     @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var myDataSource = AvailableCoursesInitialResponseModel()
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
       func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell)!
          let model = myDataSource.availableCourses[indexPath.row]

        Here i want to access the properties of **classListDetailModel** 
        my custom cell.

        cell.backgroundColor = kColorLightGray_DW
        return cell   
    }
```

How can i set the properties of `classListDetailModel` in my `UITableViewCell` subclass or how can i access the properties of `classListDetailModel`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you are passing to present view controller then you can pass the ArrayIndex along with this.what i mean is,

set this method in your actionMethod

```
let model = myDataSource.availableCourses[indexPath.row]
 // Instantiate SecondViewController
                let secondViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SecondViewController") as! SecondViewController
    //pass the model to your DataSource
    secondViewcontroller.myDataSource = model
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(secondViewController, animated: true)
```

and in your secondViewController set your Datasource

```
var myDataSource : CoursesModel!
```

now you can set the properties in your cell Like:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell: AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell)!
          let model = myDataSource.classList[indexPath.row]
 cell.lblClassName.text = model.className
      cell.lblDescription.text = //set your description from the model.
  cell.backgroundColor = kColorLightGray_DW
        return cell   
    }
```

I hope you understand What i mean. please feel free to comment in case it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure about the your UI, and the way you are handling the `indexPath`s, but you can access your list items using `model` coming from `myDataSource.availableCourses[indexPath.row]`.

Search for it @ `CoursesModel` -> `categoryDataModel` -> `classList` property.

This is an `array` of `classListDetailModel` objects, and because like i mentioned at the beginning, i am not sure about the `indexPath`s, it think they are referencing the `availableCourses` property, you can iterate through with a `forEach` to look for items one by one.

```
let cell: AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell = (NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil).first as? AvailableCoursesSecondViewControllerTableViewCell)!
let model = myDataSource.availableCourses[indexPath.row]
// All classList item, as array collection type, at a given indexPath
let classList: [classListDetailModel] = model.categoryData.classList
classList.forEach { (classListItem) in
    // Each classListDetailModel item printed
    print(classListItem)
}
```